# Send array from twig to controller symfony 2

Tags: symfony, controller, twig, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I'm trying bring the option to users that they can export the content of a table to an Excel using PHPExcel and liuggio bundle in Symfony 2.5. The problem is that I have the data in the view and I need send this results to a method in the controller to create the excel file, and I don't know a way to send this array, I know that one value can be sent easy, but a array it's complicated. If anyone knows a way to export a content from the view to controller, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You can send via AJAX, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ or create a form which represent your table.